# Custom Confirm and Alert Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="URL"> Delete </a>
```

[image]

My Alert Dialog look like above but I want to change the CSS of this ALERT.

I want to customer my ALERT and CONFIRM ALERT without change the LINK.

How can I do this?

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: you can't; the dialogue is generated by the browser, not the webpage. Unless you switch to using a dialog that is generated by the webpage instead of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ui, in that search for jquery ui alert. 
Please go through document for jquery ui alert present at jquery ui site.

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

You could refer bellow links hope this will help you
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html

[Wrong color for flash messages under Rails 4.1 with Bootstrap or Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108286/wrong-color-for-flash-messages-under-rails-4-1-with-bootstrap-or-foundation)

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#alerts

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the alert generated by the webpage, because it is not controlled by you, but by the browser, and is completely browser specific. However, you can use this custom alert, which looks great and is easy to program in:

http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Hope this helps!