# Rails Devise flash key is always being set to alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I used this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap) to add flash messages to my rails app. The alerts show up, however the key is not set to success, notice or danger. Instead when I check the class of the flash messages from the browser, it has a class of alert-alert and as a consequence isn't styled properly.

Why is devise setting the key to alert, and how can I get the right keys to be sent?

Thanks!

[UPDATE] 
The error messages like "password is too short" do show up with the class of alert-danger, but the flash messages like "you have signed in" still don't grab the right key. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This ended up working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108286/wrong-color-for-flash-messages-under-rails-4-1-with-bootstrap-or-foundation